# Managed array in VC++

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to pass a managed array from VB.NET to a function in a VC++ project. How would I declare my C++ function and how would I use the array when I'm inside it? Specifically, I want to make VB compatible functions like the one below, which is written in plain old C.

```
void Vcopy(double *A, double *B)
{
    int n;
    for(n=0;n<3;n++)
    {
        B[n]=A[n];
    }
}
```

Maybe some kind soul could convert this to something that would play nicer with VB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the C++ method be managed, e.g., C++/CLI ?
If so, then:

```
void Vcopy(array<double> ^A, array<double> ^B)
```

By the way, the rest of the method should be identical, provided that the size is 3 - otherwise use A->Length and B->Length.

Comment: Thanks a bundle! The fact that I don't have to change any other code is a huge relief, I have over 40 functions that need to be changed, some are quite large!